# Create Mongoose Find and populate from multiple tables with property set

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I'll be grateful for help with Mongoose. I have 3 tables: (Users)Table of users, (Animals)table of animals and table AnimalComments. So (AnimalComments)table reference users and animals.

```
const schemaComment = new mongoose.Schema({
        userRef: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        animalRef: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Animal'
        },
        content: {
            type: String
        }
    });

const schemaAnimal = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    isCommentedByMe: {
        type   : Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    commentCount: {
        type   : Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

What I want: I have animals. Users can add comment to animal. When user comment animal his comment is added to table AnimalComments where is stored userRef (userId), animalRef (animalId) and user comment text. Then in request response I want return all animals from table Animals but I need update property commentCount and isCommentedByMe based on value from table AnimalComments.

**Response from table Animals:**

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "isCommentedByMe": false,
            "commentCount": 0,
            "name": "Jessica",
            "userRef": {
                "id": "5dc9bdf3dd5cae00177e184d"
            },
            "id": "5dcedd48368e9800176f2ef3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response from table Users:**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Jony Cash",
            "id": "5dc9bdf3dd5cae00177e184d"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response from table AnimalComments:**

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "userRef": "5dc9bdf3dd5cae00177e184d",
            "animalRef": "5dcedd48368e9800176f2ef3",
             "content": "Sample text"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want result for exmaple:**

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "isCommentedByMe": true, 
            "commentCount": 4, 
            "name": "Jessica",
            "userRef": {
                "id": "5dc9bdf3dd5cae00177e184d"
            },
            "id": "5dcedd48368e9800176f2ef3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It would be easy to understand what you wanted, if you could give expected result.

Comment: I think you're approaching your data model a little wrong. It's not really a good idea to set one property based on something that's already stored. Instead of setting `allLikeCount` to the count of all comment likes, just total up the comment likes every time you need them. This will make sure the data is never out of sync and will always give the most accurate and up-to-date result.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I updated my question it should be clearer

Comment: @chrispytoes I updated my question it should be clearer

Comment: Please give some some sample input documents, and expected output documents

Comment: @pavol.franek Alright, so you want to add a commentCount and isCommentedByMe fields to the response, dynamically calculating it upon request time. For this you should remove those properties in your schema, since they won't actually be stored, just calculated as needed. Take a look at [MongoDB Aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Specifically you'll want to look towards the `$project`, `$lookup`, and `$sum` opertations. Mongoose can do aggregations like this: `YourModel.aggregate([<pipeline>]).exec()`.

Comment: @SuleymanSah sample input documents added

Comment: @pavol.franek I don't have time to sit down and figure out exactly what you need, but an aggregation is exactly what you're looking for. It's how you add dynamically calculated properties like running totals, sums, and averages. There's a lot you can do there probably several different ways to do what you want.

Comment: I  posted a detailed and working answer, can you check please?

Comment: @pavol.franek did you check my answer? Please give some feedback whether it worked or not.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Thank you very much, sorry I was very busy, today I try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep isCommentedByMe and commentCount fields in animal schema.

And you need to be able access comments from your animals. But in animal schema there is no field to make that connection. So we need to use virtual population.

So your animal schema must be like this:

```
const schemaAnimal = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

// Virtual populate
schemaAnimal.virtual("comments", {
  ref: "Comment",   //must be changed to the name you used for Comment model.
  foreignField: "animalRef",
  localField: "_id"
});
```

Now, we can use the following code to populate the comments.

```
router.get("/animals", async (req, res) => {
  const animals = await Animal.find({}).populate("comments");
  res.send(animals);
});
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
        "name": "Animal 1",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd66cfd069f88614c12b39a",
                "userRef": "5dd66b54c5195127ec5a1b82",
                "animalRef": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
                "content": "User 1 - Animal 1",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dd66d30069f88614c12b39d",
                "userRef": "5dd66b71c5195127ec5a1b83",
                "animalRef": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
                "content": "User 2 - Animal 1",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
        "name": "Animal 2",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd66d09069f88614c12b39b",
                "userRef": "5dd66b54c5195127ec5a1b82",
                "animalRef": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
                "content": "User 1 - Animal 2",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396",
        "name": "Animal 3",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd66d46069f88614c12b39e",
                "userRef": "5dd66b71c5195127ec5a1b83",
                "animalRef": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396",
                "content": "User 2 - Animal 3",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396"
    }
]
```

To convert this result to what you wanted, we can use map like this:

Please note that, you need to set loggedInUserId variable to logged in user's id.

```
router.get("/animals", async (req, res) => {
  const loggedInUserId = "5dd66b54c5195127ec5a1b82";

  const animals = await Animal.find({}).populate("comments");

  const result = animals.map(animal => {
    return {
      id: animal._id,
      name: animal.name,
      isCommentedByMe:
        animal.comments.filter(c => c.userRef.toString() === loggedInUserId)
          .length > 0,
      commentCount: animal.comments.length
    };
  });

  res.send(result);
});
```

The result will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
        "name": "Animal 1",
        "isCommentedByMe": true,
        "commentCount": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
        "name": "Animal 2",
        "isCommentedByMe": true,
        "commentCount": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396",
        "name": "Animal 3",
        "isCommentedByMe": false,
        "commentCount": 1
    }
]
```

And the answer for the question in the comments is: (how to reference User)

```
  const animals = await Animal.find({}).populate({
    path: "comments",
    model: Comment,
    populate: [
      {
        path: "userRef",
        model: User
      }
    ]
  });
```

This will give you the userRef like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
        "name": "Animal 1",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd66cfd069f88614c12b39a",
                "userRef": {
                    "_id": "5dd66b54c5195127ec5a1b82",
                    "name": "User 1",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "animalRef": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
                "content": "User 1 - Animal 1",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dd66d30069f88614c12b39d",
                "userRef": {
                    "_id": "5dd66b71c5195127ec5a1b83",
                    "name": "User 2",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "animalRef": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394",
                "content": "User 2 - Animal 1",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd66c73069f88614c12b394"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
        "name": "Animal 2",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd66d09069f88614c12b39b",
                "userRef": {
                    "_id": "5dd66b54c5195127ec5a1b82",
                    "name": "User 1",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "animalRef": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
                "content": "User 1 - Animal 2",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396",
        "name": "Animal 3",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd66d46069f88614c12b39e",
                "userRef": {
                    "_id": "5dd66b71c5195127ec5a1b83",
                    "name": "User 2",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "animalRef": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396",
                "content": "User 2 - Animal 3",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd66c88069f88614c12b396"
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you, my last question is. Is it possible add populate to virtual populate? Respone is now 

{
                "_id": "5dd66d09069f88614c12b39b",
                "userRef": "5dd66b54c5195127ec5a1b82",
                "animalRef": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
                "content": "User 1 - Animal 2"
            }

 I want
{
                "_id": "5dd66d09069f88614c12b39b",
                "userRef": { HERE FOR EXAMPLE FULL OBJECT NOT ONLY ID }
                "animalRef": "5dd66c7d069f88614c12b395",
                "content": "..."
            }

Comment: @pavol.franek  yes it is possible, please check the update at the end of  the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time that is all I need.